# Any implications to different eigenvalues of the Leslie matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I found out the eigenvalues of the Leslie matrix (may not be the form in Wikipedia) that describe some discrete recurrence relation between e.g. different age classes. Can I conclude anything if the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max} > 1, = 1, \in (0, 1), = 0$ or $< 0$ (this may not happen, but just in case it did)?

When $\lambda_{\max} = 1$, can I say the eigenvector I obtained is the steady-state solution to the equation system $\underline{x_{n+1}} = L\underline{x_n}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "largest" eigenvalue? Are the eigenvalues necessarily real numbers? If not, then do you mean largest in absolute value?

Comment: The fact that $1$ is an eigenvalue means that a steady state solution exists. If all other eigenvalues have magnitude less than $1$, then all trajectories converge to a steady-state solution. If the eigenvalue $1$ is simple (of algebraic multiplicity $1$), then the steady-state solution is unique.

Comment: I see. I should've said all the eigenvalues are real. So if the largest eigenvalue is 1 which is also unique, I can simply claim the steady state solution is (a multiple of) the corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: If "largest" refers to absolute value, then yes